# ActiveRecord query only if attribute is inferior than another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have the current query :

`@meals = Meal.where(week_day: 1, vacation_mode: false).order('random()')`

`Meal` has two other attributes: `max_daily_orders` and `today_orders`. Both are integers.

I want to perform the same query as mentioned above, but only get meals where `today_orders` is strictly inferior than `max_daily_orders`

for example:

- if the meal 'Hamburger' has `today_orders` equal to 6 and
  `max_daily_orders` equal to 6, it shouldn't be taken by the query.
- whereas the meal 'Fish and Chips' has `today_orders` equal to 2 and
  `max_daily_orders` equal to 8 so it should be taken by the query

How can I improve my query so that I can compare both attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have a string of what would be your query inside the where, i usually use this approach because it makes me feel like im writing plain SQL.

This should work for you:

```
@meals = Meal.where("week_day = 1 
                 AND vacation_mode = false
                 AND today_orders < max_daily_orders")
```

Comment: Thank you @RickS didn't know I could write it that way ! to avoid SQL injection security issue, I just changed it like so: `Meal.where("week_day = ? AND vacation_mode = ? AND orders_today < max_daily_orders", 1, false)`

Comment: @JulesCorb yeah that looks perfect, glad i could help.